# syntax error in awk

Tags: awk, syntax

```c
#!/usr/bin/awk

userinput='Hello World!'
userinput=$userinput awk '
    BEGIN {
        s = ENVIRON["userinput"] "\n"
        n = length(s)
        while (1)
            printf "%s", substr(s,int(1+rand()*n),1)
    }'
```

Whenever I run above code I get following error.

> awk: cmd. line:1: pass.awk
> awk: cmd. line:1:     ^ syntax error

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

awk '{
        s = $0 "\n"
        n = length(s)
        while (1)
            printf "%s", substr(s,int(1+rand()*n),1)
    }'
```

> awk: cmd. line:1: pass.awk 
> awk: cmd. line:1:     ^ syntax error

I am getting same error both time. But, I am not getting any error when I write those code and run in terminal. It was little bit weird for me. Cause, I am new to `awk`. That may be a typo error I am not sure. I had saved the file name as `pass.awk`. Running this way `awk pass.awk` or, `awk pass.awk hello`

Comment: What you have there is *a shell script that uses awk*, not an awk script - the `#!/usr/bin/awk` shebang is not appropriate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, if you want to write an `awk` script, you need to use `-f` in the shebang since `awk` requires a file, and using this is a workaround to let you use `awk` on the contents of the script. See `man awk`:

```
   -f progfile
             Specify  the pathname of the file progfile containing an awk
             program. A pathname of '-' shall denote the standard  input.
             If multiple instances of this option are specified, the con‐
             catenation of the files specified as progfile in  the  order
             specified  shall be the awk program. The awk program can al‐
             ternatively be specified in the command line as a single ar‐
             gument.
```

So, to use `awk` as your interpreter in the shebang, you need this:

```c
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{print "hello world!"}
```

What you have is a shell script that is calling `awk`, so you need a shell shebang:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

awk 'BEGIN{ print "Hello world!"}'
```

The next issue is that you have a space in your variable but are using the variable unquoted. Always quote variables in shell scripts! What you wanted was this:

```
userinput='Hello World!'
userinput="$userinput" awk '...
```

Now, here's a working version of your first (shell) script:

```
#!/bin/sh

userinput='Hello World!'
userinput="$userinput" awk '
    BEGIN {
        s = ENVIRON["userinput"] "\n"
        n = length(s)
        while (1)
            printf "%s", substr(s,int(1+rand()*n),1)
    }'
```

Note that your `while (1)` means the script will never exit, that is an infinite loop.

And here's your second script as an actual `awk` script:

```c
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
  s = $0 "\n"
  n = length(s)
  while (1)
    printf "%s", substr(s,int(1+rand()*n),1)
}
```

Comment: Why I have to use `-f` with shebang? What does that mean(What does it represent)?

Comment: @Softunes see updated answer. `-f` is how you tell `awk` to read commands from a file and in this case, the file is the script you write. But if you use `awk` in the shebang, then you must have _only_ `awk` code in the script.

Comment: the version with the shell wrapper might do with `"$@"` at the end, in case they want to pass filenames (or variable assignments) to awk. Not necessary if processing stdin is enough

Comment: @ilkkachu given what the awk program does, that wouldn't make sense here. In other cases, yes of course.

Comment: Don't call awk using a shebang at all, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002754/1745001.

Comment: Don't call awk with a shebang?   "Never" seems a bit strong, just for a use-case that's highly situational/rarely useful - especially when it's only to make use of what is arguably a bug (unfixable for legacy reasons) in awk's design (to use args with `=` in them for variable assignment, making it a) impossible to pass filenames with `=` to awk, and b) causing any such filenames to make variable assignments if used.  It's awk's equivalent of the "filename called `-rf`" problem, but without `--` to ameliorate it).

Comment: @EdMorton yeah, that seems like a very strong statement with very weak evidence to support it. I like using awk shebangs and writing pure awk scripts that can be easily manipulated in an editor (syntax highlighting, tab indentation etc.). That, for me, can outweigh the drawback of handling multiple arguments. If I need that, I'll use a shell shebang, but when I don't, using an awk shebang is more practical.

Comment: @cas & terdon calling awk with a shebang frequently leads to people trying to do things in awk that are better done in shell, passing arguments to awk in the function list where they're harder to deal with then separating them with `-v` and writing scripts that are tightly coupled to being 100% implemented in awk, etc., etc.. The only argument I've ever heard for doing it is syntax highlighting in an editor which IMHO isn't even in the ballpark of a worthwhile tradeoff and if you need then your script is too complicated.

Comment: @case You can pass file names with `=` in them to awk, you just have to specify a path, e.g. given a file named `this=file` you can pass that to awk using `awk 'script' ./this=file` instead of `awk 'script' this=file`.

Comment: FWIW I just checked the hundred+ script files I have lying around on my laptop that contain an awk script and there are only 2 of them that don't contain something that's best done outside of that awk script. It's not that I couldn't do some of it in awk (e.g. validating arguments with awk instead of using getopts, or sorting the output, or checking the input file is non-empty or getting the size of the file up front, etc) but almost every script I have is best written as a shell script, not just an awk script, so in my experience it's rare for a stand-alone awk script to be the best solution.

Comment: In my experience, all of those things are good reasons to use perl instead of awk.

Comment: @cas I assume you understand that perl and awk aren't peers. Awk is the mandatory POSIX tool for general text manipulation. Perl is a general purpose tool available on many but not all systems. Awk isn't intended to be a general purpose tool, it's intended to be called by shell when text manipulation is needed as part of solving a problem and it fills that role extremely well.

Comment: Of course they're not peers.  awk is very useful but it's a relatively simple tool for simple tasks.  perl is capable of much more, with less effort.   I use them both, a lot, but I'm not a masochist - I'll use the right tool for each job.  And yes, I understood what you meant - but I really don't care which one has the POSIX stamp of approval.  I use Linux almost exclusively these days, some FreeBSD.  And I'll never willingly use a proprietary unix again....even when I did, I had no difficulty installing perl if it wasn't already installed, same as I installed GNU utils under /usr/local/gnu.

Comment: I won't use shell when awk or sed is the right tool for the job.  And I won't use awk or sed when perl is the right tool.

Answer (score 2):

Make that first line call the shell interpreter and not awk, as in

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, awk expects a string containing the program code as the first argument on the command line. E.g.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ print "hello" }'
```

would just print `hello`. So if you run

```
awk pass.awk
```

it tries to interpret `pass.awk` as awk code. The dot isn't valid awk syntax, so an error you get.

To have awk read the code from a file, use `awk -f foo.awk`, as @terdon's answer shows. (You'll want to fix the hashbang line and remove the shell stub as shown there.)